# Pathfinder SWIFT

Tags: swift, frameworks, path-finding, a-star

Do you know any working pathfinder frameworks that I can use in my project written in swift?

I have tried these two:

1) https://github.com/colinhumber/HUMAStarPathfinder

But I don't use cocos2d in my project, so I have no idea how to implement it into my game.

2) https://github.com/iluuu1994/Pathfinder

This one doesn't work well with diagonals.

I have no idea where can I find a working pathfinding library. Any ideas?

Comment: HUMAStarPathfinder does not require cocos2d -- that's just an example. The actual API is framed in terms of an abstract tile grid. You might read up on "algorithm A*" (or "algorithm A star"). Once you understand the underlying algorithm, it will be clearer how to use the API.

Answer (score -2):

Apple has provided a pathfinding library in [GamePlayKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html).